# Short Circuit the Pipeline in Razor Pages

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-2.0, razorengine, razor-pages

I am looking to short circuit the pipeline in a .Net Core 2.1 Razor Page. Specifically, I am looking to redirect to another page if a certain condition is met without model binding or running any of the code in the page methods. In the example below, the redirect occurs but only after everything in the page methods is completed.

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        //This line will still run after the redirect called from within OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync.
        var test = 0;

        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        //This line will still run after the redirect called from within OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync.
        var test = 0;

        return Page();
    }

    public override async Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        if (true)//Some page specfic check, i.e. this will redirect to index page after 3PM.
        {
            //This line gets hit before OnGetAsnyc/OnPostAsync is called. 
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Index");
        }
    }
}
```

[This page is the link for the Razor Page filter docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but it refers to [the MVC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for pipeline short circuiting/cancellation. Unfortunately the header on the MVC filter page warns that this page's documentation doesn't apply to razor pages.

How could you get the page to abandon running any more code once a condition is met upon page selection?

*The condition is not found in a claim so a custom Authorization filter wouldn't apply.

Comment: Did you get an answer for this, @Tom?

Answer (score 4):

You can do as following. This is working for me in 3.1 version.

```cs
public void OnPageHandlerExecuting(PageHandlerExecutingContext context)
{
     if (condition is true)
     {                            
          context.Result = new RedirectResult(yourpagename);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For short circuiting, you could try `Middleware` and check the request based on your own logic like below:

```
        app.Use(async (context,next) => {
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/Product")))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Index");
            }
            await next();
        });
        app.UseMvc();
```

**Note**, use the `Middlware` before calling `app.UseMvc();`.

Answer (score 1):

Short circuiting or canceling inside an Razor Page filter is not supported. You need to implement it via [Resource Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#resource-filters).

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#cancellation-and-short-circuiting) for how to do it in a Resource Filter